# Flex 4 spark, validator message

Tags: forms, validation, apache-flex, tooltip, flex-spark

In Flex 4 Spark form the validators display the errors on the right inside the container (not floating) and this resize my application.

I want to show the errors like in Flex 3 MX: on the right in a floating tooltip (so the dimensions of the container is not resized).

Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see the answer on the [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3999737?tstart=0)?

Comment: I've posted the same question on Adobe Forums and their reply was the one I was looking for, so follow this link to find it ;)